# Why does this cell of a dataframe contain not a value, but a series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I read in a CSV to a dataframe in python. I have a DateTimeIndex and two columns I am interested in, let's call them number and upper_limit. I sort by the index, delete unnecessary columns and rows belonging to older timestamps. Then I calculate min, max and avg for both of those columns with

```
numbercol = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,0], errors='coerce')
upperlimitcol = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,1], errors = 'coerce')
```

This works fine. Now I want to check how often number is greater than upper_limit with

```
for dt in df.index:
     if numbercol[dt] >= upperlimitcol[dt]:
         overshoots += 1
```

But I get a

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I added a print statement to see the value of the number and upper_limit column for each `dt`, and it turns out that after 1800 lines, the values in the cells aren't numbers anymore, but look like this (this is what it give me for `print(numbercol[dt])`)

```
DateTime
2017-01-14       NaN
2017-01-14    3018.0
Name: Number, dtype: float64
```

The type of `numbercol[dt]` also changes from `<type 'numpy.float64'>` to `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

I examined the file in a Text Editor as well as Libre Office and Excel, but couldn't see any difference between this line and the line before. Do you have any idea why this could be?

Comment: `numbercol[dt]` is returning a series because you have two records with the same `dt`.

Comment: What does `upperlimitcol[dt]` return?  Are the timestamps unique in that dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is returning a series because you have two records with the same `dt`. Not knowing the context of your problem, it is difficult to say how to proceed.

One way would be to aggregate the data in the for loop using `sum()`or some other aggregrating function (i.e. `max()`, `min()`, etc.):

```
for dt in df.index:
   if numbercol[dt].sum() >= upperlimitcol[dt]:
       overshoots += 1
```

Another could be to dropna() before your for loop.

```
numbercol = numbercol.dropna()
```